# How to append an Object to a DOM Element with JQuery append(), add() or appendTo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this working, even though I have the idea it is perfectly correct. Consider the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
        ul = $(".qtrans_language_chooser");
        parent = ul.parent();
        activeLangLi = ul.children("li.active");

        parent.prepend('<ul class="qtrans_active_language"></ul>');
        activeLangUl = $(".qtrans_active_language");
        o = activeLangLi.appendTo(activeLangUl);
        activeLangLi.remove();
</script>
```

All I'm trying to do is add activeLangLi to the empty activeLangUl. But no matter if I use append(), appendTo() or add() it never shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
activeLangLi.remove();
```

This removes the elements from the DOM. `append` and `appendTo` will **move** (not copy) the elements from the current location to the new one. If you `remove` them afterwards, well, then they are gone.

You could also optimize your code to:

```
var ul = $(".qtrans_language_chooser");
$('<ul class="qtrans_active_language"></ul>')
    .prependTo(ul.parent())
    .append(ul.children("li.active"));
```

Don't forget to use `var`.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization. However, I could've sworn that I tried whether the remove() command was the problem by commenting it out. Then when it didn't solve the problem, I was baffled and tried out other things. Thanks!